# Not able to install opencv-python on beagle bone

Tags: python, pip, beagleboneblack, opencv

Hi there I am trying to install opencv-python on beaglebone black
I am on python 3.7.3

and I am using pip3 for installing library

I am getting this errors, Pls help me understand below errors and solve them,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 897, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 617, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/hashes.py", line 48, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 585, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 574, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
    self._close()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 86, in dumps
    data, separators=(",", ":"), sort_keys=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found the problem but solved my issue with installing apt-get install python-opencv instead of python package manager

Comment: did that (apt-get install python3-opencv) end up working for you on a beaglebone black? I've seen several posts suggesting that but haven't been able to get it to work myself and also haven't seen a conclusive post showing evidence that it worked.

Answer (score -1):

just type this code

```
pip install opencv-python
```

if you are using Jupiter notebook you can use this code

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: try it with `!`